# Divide a Data Extension into 5 segments

Tags: marketing-cloud, automation

I would like to take my data extension, divide it into 5 segments, each segment will have 6000 data, how to do that with SQL? Thank you

Comment: Please ask your question in English.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please take a few minutes to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) then [edit] your question (in English, please) to explain your requirement more clearly (e.g. what criteria are there for this segmentation - is it just by creation date or do specific values define the segment to be allocated) and to show what research you've done and where you're actually stuck. Without such details your question is likely to simply be closed without an answer.

Comment: You have asked exact same question yesterday, where you have been asked to provide more details. Asking same question, upon the old one being closed, and actually providing even less information on what you are trying to achieve, is why I closed this one too. Please edit your original question, add some example of the data fields and values you need for your segmentation, what SQL query you have tried so far, and we will do our best to help you - especially if you ask the question in English. Not all of us are fluent in French.

Answer (score 0):

No need to do this with SQL. Within the UI you can split a data extension at random and can control the number of records in each segment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_create_random_de.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Comment: Nice, though this assumes a random segmentation is what is required. The problem here is that the requirement is not clearly stated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not looking for a random DE and need to do this in an automation - I have done this before with SELECT TOP.

Something like this -

SELECT TOP 6000 FROM DataExtension -- insert into DataExtension1

Then on your next query

SELECT TOP 12000 FROM DataExtension WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID from DataExtension1) (or do a join)

...and it grows from there.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. In my DE I have two fields Email and engagement (decimal), I want to select the 6000 first top and make them in one DE then the 6000 others and so on

Comment: Yeah - the solution I reference above would work in that case.